# Getting individual file name from a list of file names separated by space in Linux shell

Tags: linux, git, shell

I have file names which I get from `git diff` command in my shell script
and it's output looks like this :

```
bewsdfsdf.txt xcvxcv.txt  # separated by space
```

My script:

```py
python3 "unitest.py"
COMMIT_ID=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
echo ${COMMIT_ID}
Files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${COMMIT_ID})
touch names.txt
echo ${Files} > names.txt
cat names.txt
```

I want to get each file name separately. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you saving `git diff`'s output to any variable etc?

Comment: To `files` variable, which is inserted into `names.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the output of this command `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${COMMIT_ID}` to [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#NAME) utility.

Using the [`-I`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#OPTIONS) argument, you can get each file name separately and execute a command for each file name (if `replace-str` is set to `%`)

For example : If you want to `echo` each file name,

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${COMMIT_ID} | xargs -I % echo %
```

Comment: Now, let's say I want to run a script with each name as the parameter,  how can I do it?

Comment: @YuvalEzrati, In the above answer, ```echo %``` is the command being run (by the xargs utility), so if you want to run a script, you can replace ```echo %``` with your script call, for example, if the script name is ```abc```, then you can replace it by ```./abc %``` where ```%``` will be replaced by the filename during execution

Comment: __Note__: Above script call ```./abc``` assumes the script to be executed is in the current directory.